# How can you combine a list of tokens and characters (including punctuation and symbols) into a single sentence string in python?

Tags: python, list

I'm trying to join a of list of words and characters such as the one below list (ls), and convert it into a single, correctly formatted sentence string (sentence) for a collection of lists.

```py
ls = ['"', 'Time', '"', 'magazine', 'said' 'the', 'film', 'was',
      '"', 'a', 'multimillion', 'dollar', 'improvisation', 'that',
      'does', 'everything', 'but', 'what', 'the', 'title', 'promises',
      '"', 'and', 'suggested', 'that', '"', 'writer', 'George',
      'Axelrod', '(', '"', 'The', 'Seven', 'Year', 'Itch', '"', ')',
      'and', 'director', 'Richard', 'Quine', 'should', 'have', 'taken',
      'a', 'hint', 'from', 'Holden', "'s", 'character', 'Richard',
      'Benson', 'who', 'writes', 'his', 'movie', ',', 'takes', 'a',
      'long', 'sober', 'look', 'at', 'what', 'he', 'has', 'wrought',
      ',', 'and', 'burns', 'it', '.', '"']
```

```py
sentence = '"Time" magazine said the film was "a multimillion dollar improvisation that does everything but what the title promises" and suggested that "writer George Axelrod ("The Seven Year Itch") and director Richard Quine should have taken a hint from Holden's character Richard Benson who writes his movie, takes a long sober look at what he has wrought, and burns it."'
```

I've tried a rule based approach that adds an empty space after an element depending on the contents of the next element but my method ended as a really long piece of code that contains rules for as many cases as I could think of like those for parenthesis or quotations. Is there a way to effectively join this list into a correctly formatted sentence more efficiently and effectively?

Answer (score 0):

I think a simple for should do the trick:

```
sentence = ""
for word in ls:
    if (word == ',' or word == '.') and sentence != '': 
         sentence = sentence[:-1] #removing the last space added
    sentence += word 
    if word != '\"' or word != '(':
         sentence += ' ' #adding a space after each word
```